# ImportError: No module named _gdb

Tags: python, gdb

I compiled gdb 12.1 from the source through command below in python 2.75

```
configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python
sudo make all install
```

then, I occurred `ImportError: No module named _gdb` error when trying to import gdb module in python.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gdb/python')
>>> import gdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _gdb
ImportError: No module named _gdb
```

Does anyone know something about this? Where the '_gdb' package comes from?

Update:

My original goal to do so is to import 'gdb_prettyprint' to gdb, like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/gdb_prettyprint/python')
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gdb/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
```

then, I encountered the same issue above.

Update:

I solved this issue by putting the code into `~/.gdbinit`. Maybe we should start the gdb app firstly and then, it will generate the `_gdb` py module?

Comment: It's in gdb itself.
Why are you trying to import gdb from python in the first place?

Comment: hi, @ssbssa. Actually, I encounter this issue when I am trying to import the function of `gdb_prettyprint ` to gdb, like this: `import sys ; sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/gdb_prettyprint/python'; sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gdb/python'); from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers ) ,
`

Comment: @clayclay  Can you clarify what you did to solve this?  "Putting the code into" begs the question: What code?